# Valid use case for @PostAuthorize And @PostFilter annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-acl

We have just migrated to Spring Security **3.0.8** from **2.0.8** (Can' upgrade to the latestversion which is **3.2.X** as our **core spring libraries** are still on **3.0.X**, which we plan to upgrade later when business permits).

I understand that we now have annotations for securing methods like `@PreAuthorize`, `@PostAuthorize`, `@Secured`, `@PreFilter` and `@PostFilter`.

I understand the use of `@PreAuthorize`, which really makes sense. But can't think of any valid use cases where you would ever use `@PostAuthorize` or `@PostFilter` annotation?

Can somebody who used it please explain to me a reasonable use-case for using them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both the `@PostAuthorize` and `@PostFilter` are used, mostly, in combination with ACL. Where the `@PostAuthorize` will generate an exception if something is returned which one hasn't access to, the `@PostFilter` will remove the objects one doesn't have access to (in general useful when returning collections of elements).

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for that explanation. It would have been even better if there was an example, nevertheless I'll accept the answer!

Answer (score 5):

`@PostFilter` filters the returned collection or arrays after executing the method. Spring security provides a built-in object named as **filterObject** at which `@PostFilter` performs filtering task.

`@PostFilter` can be used on service layer with `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize`.

Use interface to declare the filter operation.

```java
public interface IBookService {

    @PreAuthorize ("hasRole('ROLE_READ')")
    @PostFilter ("filterObject.owner == authentication.name")
    public List<Book> getBooks();
    
    @PreAuthorize("filterObject.owner == authentication.name")
    public void addBook(List<Book> books);

}
```